# New to code, running into this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new... like brand new to code and I've been working on a side project that I can progressively incorporate things I'm learning in my courses to help with internalization. I have touched on basic HTML and JS, but have a long way to go. My first page so far is a temperature calculator and now that I'm learning a little HTML I wanted to incorporate a  because I just learned about them, rather than browser prompts. However, I'm running into the error in the title for this section of code.

Here is a slice of the code I'm using that's kicking me the error

```js
//getElementById() Method testing
let userTempNumberRaw = ''
let celsius = ''
let fahrenheit = ''
let kelvin = ''
let newton = ''
let userTempUnit
let userTempNumber

// Checks the userinput for unit in the dropdown and chooses which caluclation function to call

function bigFunction(){
 userTempUnit = document.getElementById(tempUnit).value
 userTempNumberRaw = document.getElementById(tempNumber).value
 userTempNumber = parseFloat(userTempNumberRaw)
 switch (userTempUnit.toUpperCase()){
 case 'KELVIN':
  kelvinCalc(userTempNumber)
    break;
 case 'CELSIUS':
  celsiusCalc(userTempNumber)
  break;
 case 'FAHRENHEIT':
  fahrenheitCalc(userTempNumber)
  break;
 case 'NEWTON':
  newtonCalc(userTempNumber)
  break;
 }
}
```

```html
<h2> Enter your conversion information bellow. Thank you.</h2>
<!-- This segment is the submition form whereupon submit button is pressed, values are passed to our calculation functions -->
<form onsubmit="bigFunction()" action = "" method = "DIALOG">
  <br>
  <label for="temp-number">Enter the value of the temperature you are trying to convert</label>
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="tempNumber" id = "tempNumber" step = "1">
  <select id="tempUnit" name = "tempUnit">
    <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
    <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
    <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="newton">Newton</option>
    <label for="tempUnit">unit</label>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Specifically it's telling me that for both document.getElementByID(tempUnit).value and for document.getElementById(tempNumber).value are both 'value = null.'

My expected outcome for this would have been that after pressing submit, the function bigFunction() will run, thereby pulling the values just submitted to the

id="tempUnit" 
and 
id="tempNumber"

from both input fields and assigning them to the variables

userTempUnit 
and 
userTempNumberRaw.

I just don't see why it would say value is null when they have submitted the value already, with defined values like Kelvin. Do I need to return the values somehow? Thank you for your help!

The calculation functions are further down.
If I have submitted either too much or too little information I am happy to answer questions too. This is my first post.

Comment: `tempUnit` is a **variable** name, not a string ID.

Comment: you forgot to add below variables value:
    let userTempUnit = 'tempNumber';
    let userTempNumber = 'tempNumber';

Comment: Ah so I was missing the quotes around the ID causing it to try to read it as a variable. Thank you Quentin, I see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quentin commented, JS is seeing tempUnit as a variable - when you use `document.getElementById()` you need to pass a string to it that matches your element id. Try:

```
userTempUnit = document.getElementById('tempUnit').value
userTempNumberRaw = document.getElementById('tempNumber').value
```

Comment: doh, what a simple fix. It does seem to have solved my 'null' value problem. Thank you so much! My calculations are coming through clearly now in my console, but it does report an error of "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" now. Guess I'll start digging around till I know how to fix that one next!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to the world of coding : )

Answer (score -1):

You didn't define these two variables userTempUnit, userTempNumber. define it as empty.

```
let userTempUnit = '';
let userTempNumber = '';
```

Comment: Javascript seems to let me declare them with no assignment just fine. I appreciate the answer!